# Is there a reverse of Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, group-theory

The [BCH formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula) says that if $\exp(A)\exp(B) = \exp(C)$ where $C$ is a series in nested commutators of $A$ and $B$,
$$C = A + B + \frac{1}{2}[A,B] + \frac{1}{12}\Big(\big[A,[A,B]\big] + \big[B,[B,A]\big]\Big) + \cdots.$$
I was wondering if there was a way to read the equation backwards, where if you start with one exponential,
$$\exp(A+B)$$
then is it it possible to get some expression with two (or more?) exponentials, for example
$$\exp(A+B) = \exp(A)\exp(B)\exp(D).$$
I imagine that the extra $\exp(D)$ could very well be in front instead in the back, or it could be in the middle, or perhaps there are 3 extra factors that go in all 3 places. If there is, is there a specific formula for the extra factors in terms of $A$ and $B$?

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: It is called the [Zassenhaus expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker–Campbell–Hausdorff_formula#Zassenhaus_formula). You *really* should move this to MSE, as encouraged. You appear to be groping for braiding relations. Experiment with Pauli matrices.

Comment: Ah, thank you for the pointers! If this should be deleted then I have no problem with that!